# Hide some elements without occupying space in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx-8

Can anyone tell me is there any display:none property in JavaFX like in Css?

Actually I want to hide some labels and don't want them to occupy space when hidden.

How can I achieve this in JavaFX?

TIA

Answer (score 26):

Nodes are considered for layout purposes by parents as long as their `managed` property is `true`. For this reason you need to set both the `visible` and the `managed` property:

```
node.setVisible(false);
node.setManaged(false);
```

This is an alternative to simply removing the node from it's parent that allows you to make the node reappear again. If you don't want do anything with the node after hiding it, you should simply remove it from the scene instead:

```
parentLayout.getChildren().remove(node);
```

Comment: I want it hidden initially then when some button clicked it will reappear. but when hidden no space will be occupied and it's bottom element occupy its place when hidden

Comment: Of course you can set the properties to `false` initially and later change them to `true`. Alternatively `parentLayout.getChildren().add(insertionIndex, node);` but this may result in problems with getting the order right...

Comment: Thanks a million, It really helps.

Comment: Thank you! It works in javaFX Toolbar after setting some buttons to hidden.